# what's wrong in this code (array in function output nothing)?

Tags: php, mysqli

**why the array "$access_level" in protect_page function output nothing ?**

**I don't know what's wrong in this code to prevent array "access_level" from output ..
what I need to edit to fix that issue**

```
session_start();
include 'C:\xampp\htdocs\database\agtdatabase\agt_site\connection\connect.php';
if (isset($_SESSION['sessionloginid']))// point to id of user logged in
    {
    $query =
        "SELECT * 
        FROM privilege 
        where login_id='" . $_SESSION['sessionloginid'] . "'  ";

    $access_level = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('');
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {


        $_SESSION['sessionloginid'] = $row['login_id'];
        $_SESSION['sessionaccess'] = $row['AccessLevel']; //output 
        $access_level[] = $_SESSION['sessionaccess'];
        print_r ( $access_level)//output Array([0]=>1)Array([0]=>1[1]=>2) 
        }

    function protect_page()
        {

        $access_level = array();
        $access_level[] = $_SESSION['sessionaccess'];
        if (in_array(1, $access_level))
            {


//  header ('location:http://localhost/database/agtdatabase/agt_site/agtSite/agt2.php');


            print_r($access_level); //output nothing
            exit();
            }
        }

    }//end of parent if 

protect_page();
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: thank you amal .but you have misunderstand I remove header part and print_r()inside the loop output Array([0]=>1)Array([0]=>1[1]=>2)  but array outside loop and within function output nothing ..I want array within function output the array

Comment: ...because your `if` statement fails. `in_array(1, $access_level)` is __false__. http://codepad.org/kByQx5Os

Comment: I'm beginner in php .I see the code in link but I don't know what I do to fix that . Could you assist me

Comment: Being a novice, you should choose yourself a simpler task to learn on.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming what you wrote in the comments is what you see, you might want to note that

```
$access_level[]=$_SESSION['sessionaccess'];
```

adds the entire $_SESSION['sessionaccess'] array as the first element of $access_level, so $access_level is

```
Array([0]=>(Array([0]=>1[1]=>2))
```

hence it doesn't contain the value 1, hence in_array(1, $access_level ) is false, so the redirection/print_r never happen.

Andrei